# Desktop recording with Angular SPA in Electron app

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, screen-recording, desktopcapturer

I everyone. I have an application in Electron containing a SPA in Angular. Electron is used through a service that exposes its API using ipcRenderer and a javascript file that contains events derived from ipcMain.on, so that it can communicate between Electron and Angular. Angular dispatches a SEND event:

```
// The event in the Javascript file

ipcMain.on('desktop-capture', async () => {
    const sources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['window', 'screen'] });
    console.log(sources); // qui è dove si interrompe l’esecuzione
    for (const source of sources) {
      if (source.name === ‘Entire ’Screen) mainWindow.webContents.send('desktop-capture-res', [source]);
    }
  });
```

In the TS file, I initialize the desktop capture by sending the 'desktop-capture' event that takes care of getting the resource to be used (above) and sending a 'desktop-capture-res' event containing the response to the electron API.
(Below) I use the source from the Electron API to ask the user for permission to record the screen:

```
initializeDesktop() {
this.ipc.send('desktop-capture');
this.ipc?.on('desktop-capture-res', (event, source: Electron.DesktopCapturerSource) => {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({}).then((stream: MediaStream) => this.getDesktop(stream));
  console.log('DESKTOP_CAPTURE_STREAM', source);
})
};
```

I use the source from the Electron API to ask the user for permission to record the screen:

```
getDesktop(stream: MediaStream) {
setInterval(() => {
  const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'video/webm' });
  mediaRecorder.start();
  const chunks: any[] = [];
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
    chunks.push(e.data);
  };
  setTimeout(() => {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
  }, API_SEND_TIMEOUT);
  mediaRecorder.onstop = (e) => {
    const blob = new Blob(chunks.splice(0, chunks.length));
    console.log('DESKTOP_CAPTURE_BLOB', blob);
    this.videos.push(blob);
  };
}, API_SEND_TIMEOUT)};
```

This unfortunately does not work. The [Electron documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/desktop-capturer) suggests using this statement to specify the source desktop, but TS does not recognize the Mandatory property of video.

```
try {
      mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: false,
          video: {
              mandatory: {
                  chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                  chromeMediaSourceId: source.id,
                  minWidth: 1280,
                  maxWidth: 1280,
                  minHeight: 720,
                  maxHeight: 720
              }
          }
      }).then((stream) => {
      });
  }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If it's only a TS typing issue, just use `video: <any>{ mandatory: ... }` ?

Comment: the fact is that getUserMedia breaks the execution so even putting video: <any> I don't get a different result, getDisplayMedia should be used but it is not available in Electron